# Android: NullPointerException on DataOutputStream

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a sort of chat app between a phone and a pc. In order to receive from the phone I set up a socket and get its `outputStream` into a `DataOutputStream`, poll Strings from a `LinkedBlokingQueue` and send them using `writeUTF()`. But for some reason I get a null pointer exception while doing `dataOutputStream.writeUTF(input)`.

Here's the code:

```
public class txThread extends Thread{
    private LinkedBlockingQueue activityQueue;
    private Socket socket;
    private String input;

    public txThread(LinkedBlockingQueue activityQueue){
        this.activityQueue = activityQueue;
        socket = null;
        input = null;
    }

    public void run(){
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.8",1755);
            Log.d("DEBUG","THREAD_TX_CONNECTED");
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while(true){
                input = (String) activityQueue.poll();
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(input);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if (socket != null){
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        if (dataOutputStream != null){
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `poll()` returns `null` if the queue is empty - and `writeUTF()` throws a `NullPointerException` if you feed it `null`s - so do a `null`-check or *stop* that insane busy-wait:ing you are doing and do a `take()` instead.

Comment: @Jens thx, you could have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want `activityQueue.poll()` here which returns `null` if there is not a first item in the queue.

> Retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), or returns null if this deque is empty.

I think you should be using `activityQueue.take()` in your `while(true)` loop which waits for there to be an item in the queue:

> Retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.